# TabLayoutMediator with ViewPager2 is synchronizing wrong on tab selection -Android java

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

ViewPager2 is scrolling to the wrong page when I am selecting a tab from a far position. Swiping and selecting tab of loaded pages working fine. The error is only happening when the page is not loaded and scrolling animation is active. I have created a large viewpager2 with 100 pages containing Recyclerview.
[image]

My Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        ViewPager2 viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new viewPagerAdapter(this));
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, true, true,
                ((tab, position) -> tab.setText("Page: " + position))).attach();
    }


    private class viewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
        public viewPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
            super(fa);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new itemFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(itemFragment.ARG_PARAM1, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 100;
        }
    }
}
```

My Fragment

```
public class itemFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "parram1";
    int pagePosition;

    public itemFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pagePosition = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frgment_item, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Page - " + pagePosition);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new myAdapter());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 16));
    }



    private class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Myvh> {
        @Override
        public Myvh onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new Myvh(new TextView(getContext()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Myvh holder, int position) {
            int codepoint=pagePosition*700 + position;
            char[] ch=Character.toChars(codepoint);
            holder.textView.setText(String.valueOf(ch));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() { return 700; }
    }

    private class Myvh extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public Myvh(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried Recyclerview adapter instead of FragmentStateAdapter and getting same problem.
I have found some solution but not sufficient.
**Those are:**

1. Using old ViewPager(deprecated)
2. Using `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(100);` (taking huge time to load activity)
3. Disabling smoothscroll ( looks awful when swiping)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and its working fine at my end. Where did you apply `smoothscroll`?

Comment: @AndroidEngineX  new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, true, **true**,

Comment: @AndroidEngineX try selecting page-97 and it will go to page-99

Comment: Hi I tried the same. After trying only I have posted that this issue is not happening. Can you check in different device(ideally it should also work in your current device as well). Here is the video link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VnYdAD6DwmGiC_eyi2EZL-_LEk_PP5xG/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I have tried it on many devices. And the problem is still happening. This is only happening when the page load is large. The problem doesn't occur when I'm using a GridLayoutManager with only 2 columns. Your device is so fast. Please try it on a low-end device.

Comment: Can you share your recording as well? Also, your minimal reproducible project as well. You can find my project at https://drive.google.com/file/d/16NXEPBskySPT0720phGiFb7wnw7M7-WC/view?usp=share_link

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63756126/viewpager2-setoffscreenpagelimit-problem

Comment: @IsmailHossain by the way I am using, emulator and I am pretty much sure you can't have any device slower that the emulator :)